Is this usage of the semicolon correct?
Is the usage of the semicolon in the following declaration made by Obama correct? Or would it be correct to punctuate with a comma instead?
“But what I came to admire even more was his character — his deep empathy and hard-earned resilience; his fundamental decency and belief that everyone counts.
… “Through his policies and his example, Joe has reminded us of who we are at our best — a country committed to old-fashioned values like trust and honesty, kindness and hard work; a country that believes in democracy, rule of law, and accountability; a country that insists that everyone, no matter who they are, has a voice and deserves a chance at a better life.”
Source: https://x.com/BarackObama/status/1815110737095721109

It helps the reading.
The fundamental purpose of punctuation is to help the reader to understand what the author means.  In speech, one uses intonation and rhythmic devices to help split up sentences. In writing, we use punctuation to do the same. There are rules that students should follow to help them use punctuation effectively.
Obama isn't a student of English. Here he segments his list of Biden's qualities in a particular way, for a particular rhetorical effect.  To create this effect in writing, Obama wants to use a division marker that is stronger than a comma. So he has used a semicolon.  This is a rhetorical decision, not a grammar rule. It isn't correct or not-correct. It is effective.

Obama is very much a student of English. to use a metaphor. The guy is a very top-heavy intellectual.

I mean "student of English" in the sense of an EAL student, an English learner.

@JamesK Very helpful answer! Thank you. Apologies, I should have made it clear that I'm asking specifically how to punctuate it in writing as a student/proofreader. I was faced with proofreading a passage employing the same rhetorical effect--very much like the one in the first paragraph which doesn't use commas within the clauses. I, too, wanted to maintain the writer's intonation and rhetorical effect. So would you say it would be correct for me to punctuate it in the same manner as demonstrated in the OP?

That's a very hard question to answer, though I find
Seowjooheng's answer to be useful.  If in doubt, just use commas.  They are less distracting and are very often correct.  There would have been no grammar error if Obama had used a comma, but the two-level structure of Obama's list does point to the use of a semicolon, even though as the sub-lists only have two items each, he hasn't used a comma in the sub-lists.

Here we have three noun phrases starting with a country.  The first two contain series with themes crafted for effective communication, and the third has a pair of bracketing commas.
Generally, we separate items in a series with listing commas.  If there are several series, we further segregate each series from the next with a semicolon to differentiate the punctuation mark from the listing commas.
We look at the first two noun phrases; I’ve added the brackets for ease of discussion:

... [a country committed to old-fashioned values like trust and honesty, kindness and hard work]; [a country that believes in democracy, rule of law, and accountability]; ...

Here trust and honesty are considered as one item.
If commas are used instead of semicolons, the passage will be harder to read because of the two layers of commas:
... a country committed to old-fashioned values like trust and honesty, kindness and hard work, a country that believes in democracy, rule of law, and accountability, [and] a country that insists that everyone, no matter who they are, has a voice and deserves a chance at a better life.
I've added the required conjunction before the last noun phrase.

Thank you for the insight. Helpful indeed. While I know the last item in a series should be preceded by a conjunction, I usually cannot decide whether to retain the author's stylistic effect (who deliberately writes it without the conjunction for rhetorical effect) or to insert the conjunction according to conventional grammar rules. May I know what you would advise a proofreader?

@Seem, This is called Asyndetic Coordination (or Asyndeton).  This rhetorical device works to ‘make a speech more dramatic and effective by speeding up its rhythm and pace’.
I have not used it before and am unable to advise proofreaders.
